# Who was the first known philosopher to posit that mathematical thoerems are too idealized to represent anything in reality?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

Also how did this concept evolved?

Comment: Your questions are growing ever shorter by the day. You are unlikely to inspire people to spend time on answering questions that you spend so little time to ask (let alone research). And the ability of single lines to express anything cogently answerable is very limited, this one being no exception.

Comment: Sorry @Conifold, I did not mean to imply that YOUR assertion was not correct, I meant the OP's.

Comment: I am sorry @Conifold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Plato or Eudoxus said something before, but Aristotle certainly believed that mathematics weren't capable of describing nature. For him, mathematics concerns objects not capable of autonomous existence, while natural philosophy concerns with objects that are.

(edit) For this short answer I recount the brief mention of mathematics, physics and theology present in Alejandro Vigo's 2006 book *Aristóteles. Una introducción*.

Comment: Can you add some references to your answer?

Comment: @GEP done! sadly i wasn't able to find an english version of that book. i'd also would like to add that my answer is based on the discussion of the topic that took place on a class on philosophy of science.